# Pass variables without model associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a variable that I want to pass with a form in rails.

The variable is not convenient because it is not part of the model. I really don't want to create a column in the DB just so I can pass the variable.

When I try to pass the variable using something innocuous like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="blah" value=<%= "#{@blah}" %> />
```

The hidden field turns up correctly in the source, but doesn't pass with the params hash. When I code it properly with something like `id="review_blah"` rails assumes it's part of the review model and gets angry because it isn't part of the model.

Isn't there some workaround?? Some way to pass a variable easily for these circumstances, without rebuilding your model?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried params[:blah] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an `attribute_accessor` for the virtual attribute and you need to add it to the `attr_accessible` list so it can be used in form. Like this:

```
attr_accessor :blah
```

This makes the `blah` and `blah=` methods available which you can use to deal with the incoming data.

```
def blah=(data)
  #do sth. with the submited data here
end
```

In this case you could access the data entered in the "blah" field as the local variable "data".

Then you need to make it a part of the regular form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :blah, :value => <Your value here> %>
```

So the last thing you need to do is adding the field to the `attr_accessible` list.

```
attr_accessible :blah,....
```

Otherwise the request would fail because of mass assignment protection.

Answer (score 2):

In model

```
attr_accessible :blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's very ugly you can do something like following

```
<input name='x' type="hidden" id="blah" value=<%= "#{@blah}" %> />
```

in your controller

```
@model.save
  Model.update_all({:my_attribute => params['x']}, {:id => @model.id})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name of the input parameter I think. otherwise it will not be contained in Rails params hash.

```
<input type="hidden" id="blah" value=<%= "#{@blah}" %> name="blah"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ModelName
  attr_accessor :blah
end

@model = ModelName.new
@model.blah = "blah blah"
@model.blah  #will return "blah blah"
```

You don't need to have a column in your table. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180713/virtual-attributes-in-rails-model)
This way you can have

```
=form_for @model do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :blah
```

This will pass `blah` along the object in the `params` hash.