# How to Pass Form Field Values to a Different Controller View in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 6 app, I have a Product and Order model.

On my products#show page, I have some fields and a button.  What I need to do is send the info to the orders#new page so that this data is shown on the orders#new page.

I have tried to write some code based on [Pass variables without model associations in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912389/pass-variables-without-model-associations-in-rails) and [how to pass parameters in params using form_tag method in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937799/how-to-pass-parameters-in-params-using-form-tag-method-in-rails), but my code seems completely wrong.

on products#show:

```
<%= form_tag(new_order_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.input_field :comments %>
  <%= form.button %>
<% end %>
```

With this code I get `undefined method` text_field' for nil:NilClass`.

I have tried adding `attr_accessor :comments` to both the Product and Order model, but it doesn't help.

I don't think that my approach or what I am trying to code is right.  I was just trying to piece together parts from these answers.

Can someone please help me figure out the best way I can pass this data to Orders#new to show in that view?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing a POST to the new action of OrdersController, use method: :get as indicated by @h4ppyr0gu3. To initialise a new Order object with the sent values you can access the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_with url: "/search", method: :get do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :query, "Search for:" %>
  <%= form.text_field :query %>
  <%= form.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

from the docs

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

and the show path also requires an id